# Best practise for reading from a USB stick in real mode

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, bootloader, bios

I am writing my own bootloader for an x86 processor, and my aim is to read the second sector (following the bootloader) which would contain a kernel. Eventually the system would boot from a USB stick. I use qemu for testing purposes so ideally it would work there too.

I intend to read the kernel while in real mode but then jump to it after switching to protected mode. That way I can use the BIOS interrupt `0x13`, though I do plan to eventually write a driver when out of real mode. However I do not know the best practise to go about this.

I could use `ah = 0x02` and use CHS but [research](https://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?t=37343&p=309821) has suggested that this is not the best idea. LBA with `ah=0x42` is recommended instead. However, this extended BIOS function can only be used if the BIOS emulates the USB as a hard disk, not an FDD (as some might). So, this method might not be compatible on all systems.

Given the limitations associated with CHS but the potential infeasibility of LBA, what is my best option? I have done much research on this and other questions have as yet not helped.

Comment: You can try function 42h if available and fall back to function 02h else.

Comment: If you want to make it compatible with all systems, you better stick with LBA. The number of sectors, heads are variant and this can make things more complicated. You can do what @ecm said, but instead, you can simply use a bootloader and then implement PCI and USB (OHCI, XHCI, etc.) drivers. This makes the setup compatible with various systems and you can just implement what you want, with minimum effort.

Comment: @FurkanÇetinkaya : :LBA is generally not supported on devices in FDD (Floppy emulation mode) which is often popular as a legacy boot option with many legacy BIOSes. As ECM pointed out. This isn't compatible with all system configurations. The best way is to detect if disk extensions are supported (0x42 and LBA support) and if not fall back to CHS (0x2). The code for CHS isn't overly complicates and the calculations are well documented and easy to implement with 16 bit instructions.

Comment: PCI and USB (OHCI, XHCI, etc.) driver isn't a minimum effort. You can spend a lot of time on that just to get to the minimal effort to write code on top of that to do disk reads and writes.

Answer (score 2):

What is your ultimate goal for this exercise? Do you just want to learn about the x86 and kernels without having to worry about storage devices right now, or do you want to create the next Linux - something that others can run on their machines?

If your interest is in how kernels work, then look for an old PC with simple hardware and use whatever BIOS interrupt works for you. Writing a driver for an IDE drive, or SATA in IDE mode, will be *a lot* easier than writing a PCIe M.2 or USB driver.

If you want to create something that many others can run, then you should probably be looking at using UEFI for your bootloader.